# winforms visual styles on mono

Tags: c#, winforms, mono, gnome, visual-styles

How to enable winforms visual styles in mono( probably running in fedora or ubuntu gnome) or is it a good idea to just use GTK#? The thing is I dont want to leave visual studio and use monodevelop for this. Thanks...

Comment: Visual Studio only exists on Windows. If you don't want to use the cross-platform MonoDevelop, I can assure you testing your WinForms app on anything but Windows will be hell.

Comment: Ok, I guess I'll be using monodeveop now. What I hesitate on using it is because of the difference of windows form controls from gtk# controls.

Answer (score 2):

Winforms visual styles are more or less emulated in Mono but the appearance is not exactly the same as on Windows. It *will* work, tho.

I suggest you use GTK# if you plan running on linux indeed.

Comment: +1, I can provide some evidence, http://www.flickr.com/photos/lextm/4573111075/in/photostream This application was developed in VS, and looks well on Mono. But to make a native look application on Linux, GTK# is a must.